# Python OpenCV real-time blurring with saving to output

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have a live video stream via RTSP from my IP camera. I want to blur faces on that stream and output for mobile usage (HLS, H.264, etc). All this should ideally happen in real-time -- with the minimum of resources consumed. I plan to deploy this later to some cloud, so the less money I spend on resources the better.

Currently I have a working solution like so:

- I capture video using OpenCV
- I update every frame with Gaussian Blur and save it to some folder
- After some amount of frames I create MP4 / AVI / whatever video and make it accessible via HTTP URL
- All of it is running on Django for now

I know I am doing something wrong, can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: 1. capture. 2. detect face and blur it using mosaic 3. stream current frame over ip.   for simple stream you can follow this link https://gist.github.com/Tryptich/2a15909e384b582c51b5.   the face detect and capture sample you can find on opencv samples. whats the difficulty?

Comment: Well. 1. I am capturing, this step is ok. 2. I am ok with blurring with libraries on python. 3. My solution is python based (and your script is in C++). Do you have any info how to stream frames directly over ip in python? Is this ok practice?

Comment: you can use python system call to call ffmepg and do the encoding with some life feed at a virtual port in /dev/videoN.  ffmpeg will stream to RTSB or http